# linear programming with non-integer constraints

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose we have a linear progamming of vertex packing for a hypergraph (V,E), with size $n = \sum_{e \in E} |e|$. We introduce a variable $x_v$ for each vertex $v \in V$. The integral version is stated as follows:

$$\max \sum_{v \in V} x_v $$
$$s.t. \ \sum_{v: v \in e} x_v \le 1, \forall e \in E$$
$$\ \ \ \ x_v \in \{0,1\}$$

We have anonther version of this LP with non-integer constraints as follows:

$$\max \sum_{v \in V} x_v $$
$$s.t. \ \sum_{v: v \in e} x_v \le 1, \forall e \in E$$
$$\ \ \ \ x_v \in \{0, \log_N 2, \log_N 3, \cdots,  1\}$$

Let the optimal solution for these two LPs as $OPT_1$ and $OPT_2$.

Is there any good upper bound for $\frac{OPT_1}{OPT_2}$ in terms of n and N?